# How to open a document set staying in the same tab?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set

i have created a new document set,but when opening the latter it opens in a new tab, is there a way to open it the same tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that its possible in the classic experience mode. Note you have to change the individual library /list settings to classic experience and go to sharepoint admin and set the list/library settings there to classic also